# Set dynamically digits for EditText - Android

Tags: android-edittext, digits, android-inputtype

I want to limit an EditText field to English characters and numbers only.

I can do this in the xml section as follows

```
android:digits = "..."
```

and dynamically as follows;

```
editText.keyListener = DigitsKeyListener.getInstance(Util.ENGLISH_LANGUAGE_DIGITS)
```

However, only a keyboard with numbers appears, so there is no clickable letter but digits work correctly (I tested with copy paste).

Problem: Both the letter and the number should appear on the keyboard.

```
editText.keyListener = DigitsKeyListener.getInstance(Util.ENGLISH_LANGUAGE_DIGITS)
editText.inputType = InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT
```

I tried this but it loses its DigitsKeyListener feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution

```
editText.keyListener = DigitsKeyListener.getInstance(Util.ENGLISH_LANGUAGE_DIGITS)
editText.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT)
```